# How to set up CodeceptJS in a monorepo

Tags: pnpm, codeceptjs, pnpm-workspace

I am using a pnpm workspace with different packages to distinguish the modules. I intend to use [CodeceptJS](https://codecept.io/) as my test automation framework but whenever I install and initialize CodeceptJS in the root directory (`pnpm add -w codeceptjs playwright` then `pnpm dlx codeceptjs init`), it is not recognized within the individual packages.

If I do `pnpm dlx codeceptjs init` within a package, it gives this warning: *"WARNING: CodeceptJS is not installed locally. It is recommended to switch to local installation"* and then installs CodeceptJS in that package. Is it possible to have one shared instance of CodeceptJS with Playwright for a monorepo setup as opposed to installing it one-by-one in all packages?

Here is my directory structure:

```
root
├──node_modules
│  
├──packages
│  ├──package1
│  │   ├──node_modules
│  │   └──package.json
│  └──package2
│     ├──node_modules
│     └──package.json
|  
└──package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run the locally installed instance of `codeceptjs`, you need to run one of these commands:

```
pnpm exec codeceptjs init
```

or

```
pnpm codeceptjs init
```

[`pnpm dlx`](https://pnpm.io/cli/dlx) downloads the package and executes it.

Unlike `npx`, which is checking if a package exists locally and runs it or installs it in a hidden location, pnpm has two separate commands. One for just running a local package ([`pnpm exec`](https://pnpm.io/cli/exec)) and another one for downloading and running.

Comment: Works fine. For CodeceptJS in particular, when you do `pnpm exec codeceptjs init` in the package and select that you want to use Typescript, it will still install Typescript and CodeceptJs in that package. I guess it's written into the CodeceptJS init wizard. You can fix this by manually uninstalling CodeceptJS and Typescript from that package so that you're left with the root installations